# Is there an Excel formula for my specific scenario

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Column A is ID and Column B is Product. Column C was manually generated but I am trying to find an EXCEL formula to generate Column C.
My goal is to identify in column C IDs with multiple different products. So for example Row 1 and 2 have the same ID but two different products. However Row 7,8 & 11,12,13 have the same ID and same product... My challenge is to deal with scenarios like row 7,8 & 11,12,13 where ID and Product are repeated but should be counted as No. I cannot seem to find a formula and I have been trying to build something with Count IF. Following is a link to image which shows the data:[Sample Data Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NepAP.png)

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: I use Excel 2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in C2, the formula you need would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, "<>" & B2)>0, "Yes", "No")
```

Then copy that formula down for the rest of column C.

Comment: Thanks Spencer. It worked perfectly. I just wanted to understand the logic behind "<>" & B2>0. The rest is clear, only this part I would like to better understand.

Comment: `"<>" & B2` means ' is not equal to B2'. So `COUNTIFS(A:A. A2. B:B, "<>" & B2)` means 'Number of items where their A-column value equals A2 and their B-column value is not B2'. Where that number is more than 0 `>0`, it returns `yes`